# Write Jenkins build result to JSON

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create JSON output of a Jenkins build using Groovy's JsonBuilder and the Groovy PostBuild Plugin.  Everything seems to be working except the build result.  Instead of giving me the actual result of the build in the JSON output it is giving me an array of all possible results (i.e. SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, FAILURE, etc.).  If I just print out the result to the console it prints just the actual result.

Here is the code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def result = manager.build.result
manager.listener.logger.println result       // Prints just the build result

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def root = json.build {
    build_number manager.build.number
    build_timestamp manager.build.timestamp
    build_duration manager.build.duration 
    build_url manager.build.url
    build_project_name manager.build.project.name
    build_culprits manager.build.culprits
    build_result result                  // Prints an array of all possible results
    build_result manager.build.result    // Also prints an array of all possible results
}

manager.listener.logger.println "...and the status is ${result}"     // Prints just the   build result
manager.listener.logger.println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())
```

Here is the output:

```
UNSTABLE
...and the status is UNSTABLE
{
    "build": {
        "build_number": 85,
        "build_timestamp": "2014-01-14T13:26:06+0000",
        "build_duration": 0,
        "build_url": "job/JSON_Test/85/",
        "build_project_name": "JSON_Test",
        "build_culprits": [

        ],
        "build_result": {
            "names": [
                "SUCCESS",
                "UNSTABLE",
                "FAILURE",
                "NOT_BUILT",
                "ABORTED"
            ],
            "completeBuild": true
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried various different syntax combinations for the variable result such as $result, ${result} and ${result} in the json.build block, but all result in compile errors.

Comment: Can you try `build_result result.toString()`

Comment: Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is an instance of `hudson.model.Result`, an I think it's attempting to serializing [the whole class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Result.java). You just want the String output from printing the `result` class.

A quick fix would be:

```
def root = json.build {
    build_number manager.build.number
    build_timestamp manager.build.timestamp
    build_duration manager.build.duration 
    build_url manager.build.url
    build_project_name manager.build.project.name
    build_culprits manager.build.culprits
    build_result result.toString() // get the string representation
    // or:
    // build_result result.exportedObject
}
```